# Jquery applying a css style to all elements with a certain class except the mouseover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, fade

How can I do this? I have a list of divs:

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div id="portfolio_img1" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img2" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img3" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img4" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img5" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img6" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img7" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img8" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img9" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img10" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img11" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img12" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img13" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img14" class="portfolio_img"></div>
    <div id="portfolio_img15" class="portfolio_img"></div>
</div>
```

And I want a class "white overlay" to be applied to all of the divs except the one that has the mouse over it. Also I would like this class to fade on and off (500ms) so that there is not a sudden change in the brightness of my photos.

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify when do you want this class to be added? On mouseover on portfolio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the class to all images and remove it from the image div on hover. You would animate css class switching by using `JQuery UI` `SwitchClass()` method, however If you only want to change the transparency I think the following is easier:

```
$('div.portfolio_img').fadeTo(500, 0.5);

$('div.portfolio_img').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
});
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JvUJe/).

Comment: That's not a bad way of doing it, I personally think it could be simpler. Also, your example is not the same as the question asked. No classes are being added...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".portfolio_img").hover(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".portfolio_img").not(this).stop().fadeTo(500,0.2);
    }, function(){
        $(".portfolio_img").stop().fadeTo(500,1);
    });
});
```

This styles all `portfolio_img` divs when you hover over one of them (and it excludes the one you hovered over). Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/8yQy5/).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsFiddle example for you in the simplest and easiest way of doing it.

```
    $('.portfolio_img').hover(function(){
        $('.portfolio_img').not(this).toggleClass('white_overlay');
    });
```

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/6yeU6/

** EDIT

I have added CSS3 transition for the Fade effect too. Check the jsFiddle above.

```
 -moz-transition: background-color ease-in-out .3s;
 -webkit-transition: background-color ease-in-out .3s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.portfolio .portfolio_img').addClass('white overlay');

$('.portfolio_img').hover(function() {
  elem = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
  $(elem).removeClass('white overlay').fadeTo(500, 1);
}, function() {
  elem = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
  $(elem).addClass('white overlay').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
});
```